# Error using fetch in API call in D3 / Observable

Tags: d3.js

I have a problem with D3 fetching the data from an API. I am hosting the API on my local server but I am also exposing it through a domain name externally. It works perfectly fine for other apps accessing it and externally it can be accessed just by typing the below https query. But when I am in Observable I am trying to fetch it using the fetch command...

```
oneQuery = (await fetch("https://domain.name:port/apicall")).json()
```

I get this Error and I couldn't find anything on it explaining what it means.

```
TypeError: Origin https://myusername.static.observableusercontent.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I tried replacing domain.name with the local IP address of the API but that gives the same Error.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try your URL with JSFiddle (Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/0vg9dfsq/) Does ot work?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky it says [object Error] { ... } in the console when I try and run it with my API address or local IP address even though in a browser it returns data in the format [{"...","..."},{"...","..."}] which works fine with other json parsers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Can you post your json URL? Or the screenshot of your console?

Comment: The problem is with CORS policy of your server

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky aha I am running the API on a standard apache install. so I should be abe to enable the  -> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in the Apache Config file?

Comment: I'm a Front-end person so I don't think I can answer your question properly. I suggest to ask a new question with relevant server-side information and tags